# Setting up phroute in a subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im trying to set up [phroute](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) in a subdirectory. This is what I have done so far to get it to work, but without success.

First. In a folder I choose to call `framework`, I ran `composer require phroute/phroute`.

Second. Then I created a `/public` folder. So now in folder `framework` I have:

```
composer.json
composer.lock
public
vendor
```

Third. In folder `/public` i touch `index.php` and add the following:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;

$router = new RouteCollector();

$router->get('/', function(){ 
    return 'Hello,
```

Fourth. In the subfolder `framework` i touch `.htaccess` and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /framework/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

So when i hit `http://localhost:8888/framework/` its just blank, no errors no nothing. When just have some lorum ipsum in `index.php`, it is displayed.

The folder structure is like this:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── public
│   └── index.php
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── bin
    ├── composer
    │   ├── ClassLoader.php
    │   ├── LICENSE
    │   ├── autoload_classmap.php
    │   ├── autoload_namespaces.php
    │   ├── autoload_psr4.php
    │   ├── autoload_real.php
    │   ├── autoload_static.php
    │   └── installed.json
    └── phroute
        └── phroute
            ├── LICENSE
            ├── README.md
            ├── benchmark
            │   └── simple.php
            ├── composer.json
            ├── examples
            │   ├── route_filters.php
            │   ├── route_prefix.php
            │   ├── route_prefix_and_filter_nested.php
            │   └── simple.php
            ├── phpunit.xml
            ├── src
            │   └── Phroute
            │       ├── Dispatcher.php
            │       ├── Exception
            │       │   ├── BadRouteException.php
            │       │   ├── HttpException.php
            │       │   ├── HttpMethodNotAllowedException.php
            │       │   └── HttpRouteNotFoundException.php
            │       ├── HandlerResolver.php
            │       ├── HandlerResolverInterface.php
            │       ├── Route.php
            │       ├── RouteCollector.php
            │       ├── RouteDataArray.php
            │       ├── RouteDataInterface.php
            │       ├── RouteDataProviderInterface.php
            │       └── RouteParser.php
            └── test
                └── Dispatcher
                    └── DispatcherTest.php
```

I think it might have something to do with the `.htaccess` file. But I have no ide what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following

```
$dispatcher = new Phroute\Phroute\Dispatcher($router->getData());
echo $dispatcher->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

i had the problem too. Regards